# Get the count of how many models contain a child model with an integer greater than 1

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm, django-3.0

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company


class GroupAssessment(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='group_assessments')
    placibo_drug = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company.company


class UserAssessment(models.Model):
    group_assessment = models.ForeignKey(GroupAssessment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_assessments')
    risk = models.IntegerField()
```

Lets say there's 2 `GroupAssessment`, one called *Apple* another called *Microsoft*:

```
>>> GroupAssessment.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<GroupAssessment: Apple>, <GroupAssessment: Microsoft>]>
# 2 groups
```

10 `UserAssessment` belong to `GroupAssessment` *Microsoft*. 3 have a risk greater than or equal to 1.
12 belong to *Apple* with no risks.

How would I get the count of how many *GroupAssessment* have *UserAssessment* risk that's `greater than or equal to 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this filtering by the `user_assessments` and grouping by id:

```
    query = GroupAssessment.objects.filter(user_assessments__risk__gte=1).annotate(num_groups=Count('id'))
    print(query.num_groups)
```

Comment: This seems to give me the total count of `UserAssessment` objects that are `gte=1` via `GroupAssessment`  but not the total count of `GroupAssessment` that have `UserAssessment` objects that are `gte=1`

Comment: Could you paste here the SQL query that was generated? (by printing GroupAssessment.objects.filter(user_assessments__risk__gte=1).query)

Comment: SELECT "app_groupassessment"."id",
       "app_groupassessment"."company_id",
       "app_groupassessment"."placibo_drug"
FROM "app_groupassessment"
INNER JOIN "app_userassessment" ON ("app_groupassessment"."id" = "app_userassessment"."group_assessment_id")
WHERE "app_userassessment"."risk" >=  1